# why the limiter line code between 1 and 100 is not working and skips it

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, primes

```
System.out.println("introduza um numero entre 1 e 100: "); //input nums between 1 and 100 

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = sc.nextInt();

int count = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

    if (num % 1 == 00) {
        count++;
    }

}if (count == 2) {
    System.out.println("É número primo"); //"Num is prime"

*}else if (num <= 0 && num > 100) { //limiting the numbers input 1-100 and not working*
System.out.println("Reler enunciado"); //read again 


}else{
    System.out.println("Não é número primo"); //Num not prime

//already tried to put it here (without elseif, only if) - if (...){
```

tried with for statment and couldn't do it either

Comment: `num%1 == 0` is always true. `n/1` has a remainder of 0 for all `n ∈ Z`

Comment: `if (num <= 0 && num > 100)` This can never be true. You want OR.

Comment: `if (num % 1 == 00)` I think that's a typo. Did you mean `if (num % i == 0) {` ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find all prime numbers between 0 to input limit,
this will work.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Limit: ");
        int limit = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
            if (isPrimeNumber(i)) {
                System.out.println(i+" is a prime number");
                continue;
            }
           System.out.println(i+" is not a prime number");
        }
    }


    private static boolean isPrimeNumber(int num) {
        if (num < 2) {
            return false;
        }

        int n = num / 2;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```